# implement return into prefab class

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am using box2d and using the b2contactlistener to detect when two objects collide, One of my shapes is odd so I used the box2d PhysicsEditor to implement my shapes http://www.physicseditor.de/ and now need to use the b2Fixture of the object for the b2contactlistener... since this is all handled by the physicsEditor now along with its accompanying class I don't know how to find the b2Fixture of my shape... here are the two physics editor classes...

GB2ShapeCache.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Box2D.h>

/**
 * Shape cache 
 * This class holds the shapes and makes them accessible 
 * The format can be used on any MacOS/iOS system
 */
@interface GB2ShapeCache : NSObject 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *shapeObjects;
    b2Fixture *ColliderFixture;
}

+(GB2ShapeCache *)sharedShapeCache;

/**
 * Adds shapes to the shape cache
 * @param plist name of the plist file to load
 */
-(void) addShapesWithFile:(NSString*)plist;

/**
 * Adds fixture data to a body
 * @param body body to add the fixture to
 * @param shape name of the shape
 */
-(void) addFixturesToBody:(b2Body*)body forShapeName:(NSString*)shape;

/**
 * Returns the anchor point of the given sprite
 * @param shape name of the shape to get the anchorpoint for
 * @return anchorpoint
 */
-(CGPoint) anchorPointForShape:(NSString*)shape;


@end
```

Gb2ShapeCache.mm

```
#import "GB2ShapeCache.h"

#if defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED)
#   define CGPointFromString_ CGPointFromString
#else
// well - not nice but works for now
static CGPoint CGPointFromString_(NSString* str)
{
    NSString* theString = str;
    theString = [theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{ " withString:@""];
    theString = [theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" }" withString:@""];
    NSArray *array = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    return CGPointMake([[array objectAtIndex:0] floatValue], [[array objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]);
}
#endif

/**
 * Internal class to hold the fixtures
 */
class FixtureDef 
{
public:
    FixtureDef()
    : next(0)
    {}

    ~FixtureDef()
    {
        delete next;
        delete fixture.shape;
    }

    FixtureDef *next;
    b2FixtureDef fixture;
    int callbackData;
};

/**
 * Body definition
 * Holds the body and the anchor point
 */
@interface BodyDef : NSObject
{
@public
    FixtureDef *fixtures;
    CGPoint anchorPoint;
}
@end


@implementation BodyDef

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        fixtures = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    delete fixtures;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end


@implementation GB2ShapeCache


+ (GB2ShapeCache *)sharedShapeCache
{
    static GB2ShapeCache *shapeCache = 0;
    if(!shapeCache)
    {
        shapeCache = [[GB2ShapeCache alloc] init];
    }
    return shapeCache;
}

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        shapeObjects = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [shapeObjects release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) addFixturesToBody:(b2Body*)body forShapeName:(NSString*)shape
{
    BodyDef *so = [shapeObjects objectForKey:shape];
    assert(so);

       FixtureDef *fix = so->fixtures;
    while(fix)
    {
        body->CreateFixture(&fix->fixture);
        fix = fix->next;
    }

}

-(CGPoint) anchorPointForShape:(NSString*)shape
{
    BodyDef *bd = [shapeObjects objectForKey:shape];
    assert(bd);
    return bd->anchorPoint;
}

-(void) addShapesWithFile:(NSString*)plist
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plist
                                               ofType:nil
                                          inDirectory:nil];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSDictionary *metadataDict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"metadata"];
    int format = [[metadataDict objectForKey:@"format"] intValue];
    float ptmRatio =  [[metadataDict objectForKey:@"ptm_ratio"] floatValue];

    NSAssert(format == 1, @"Format not supported");

    NSDictionary *bodyDict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"bodies"];

    b2Vec2 vertices[b2_maxPolygonVertices];

    for(NSString *bodyName in bodyDict) 
    {
        // get the body data
        NSDictionary *bodyData = [bodyDict objectForKey:bodyName];

        // create body object
        BodyDef *bodyDef = [[[BodyDef alloc] init] autorelease];

        bodyDef->anchorPoint = CGPointFromString_([bodyData objectForKey:@"anchorpoint"]);

        // iterate through the fixtures
        NSArray *fixtureList = [bodyData objectForKey:@"fixtures"];
        FixtureDef **nextFixtureDef = &(bodyDef->fixtures);

        for(NSDictionary *fixtureData in fixtureList)
        {
            b2FixtureDef basicData;

            basicData.filter.categoryBits = [[fixtureData objectForKey:@"filter_categoryBits"] intValue];
            basicData.filter.maskBits = [[fixtureData objectForKey:@"filter_maskBits"] intValue];
            basicData.filter.groupIndex = [[fixtureData objectForKey:@"filter_groupIndex"] intValue];
            basicData.friction = [[fixtureData objectForKey:@"friction"] floatValue];
            basicData.density = [[fixtureData objectForKey:@"density"] floatValue];
            basicData.restitution = [[fixtureData objectForKey:@"restitution"] floatValue];
            basicData.isSensor = [[fixtureData objectForKey:@"isSensor"] boolValue];
            int callbackData = [[fixtureData objectForKey:@"userdataCbValue"] intValue];

            NSString *fixtureType = [fixtureData objectForKey:@"fixture_type"];

            // read polygon fixtures. One convave fixture may consist of several convex polygons
            if([fixtureType isEqual:@"POLYGON"])
            {
                NSArray *polygonsArray = [fixtureData objectForKey:@"polygons"];

                for(NSArray *polygonArray in polygonsArray)
                {
                    FixtureDef *fix = new FixtureDef();
                    fix->fixture = basicData; // copy basic data
                    fix->callbackData = callbackData;

                    b2PolygonShape *polyshape = new b2PolygonShape();
                    int vindex = 0;

                    assert([polygonArray count] <= b2_maxPolygonVertices);
                    for(NSString *pointString in polygonArray)
                    {
                        CGPoint offset = CGPointFromString_(pointString);
                        vertices[vindex].x = (offset.x / ptmRatio) ; 
                        vertices[vindex].y = (offset.y / ptmRatio) ; 
                        vindex++;
                    }

                    polyshape->Set(vertices, vindex);
                    fix->fixture.shape = polyshape;

                    // create a list
                    *nextFixtureDef = fix;
                    nextFixtureDef = &(fix->next);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // circles are not yet supported
                assert(0);
            }
        }

        // add the body element to the hash
        [shapeObjects setObject:bodyDef forKey:bodyName];
    }
}



@end
```

Basically normally when I make a new object for the world I add the new b2body and b2FixtureDef and there I can add b2Fixture = "w/e" and now since all that code is handled by the physicsEditor which I outlined my shape with idk where to set my b2Fixture = "w/e"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering late.

you can get the fixtures of any body as

```
b2Fixture *fixList = body->GetFixtureList();
```

you can then iterate over them. if you have only one, then you can delete it bcoz thats what you want.